U-Boot doesn't load boot script from NVME
Is this possible to boot Rpi CM4 + io-board  completely from NVME ?
I updated Rpi bootloader and it loads kernel well without U-boot.
When I switch to U-boot, it doesn't load boot.scr located in the same FAT partition. It tries mmc, usb but never nvme drive.
What is my problem ?

As of this writing, no, U-Boot does not support NVMe on the Pi 5.
Edit: And by the same token, no, it does not support NVMe on the rest of the Pi family either.

yeah, it seems like that... it simply doesn't even try to search for boot.scr located on NVME partition

The answer is about the Pi 5, but the question was about the CM4. These boot differently, as far as I'm aware.

Yes, that's possible. Source: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/raspberry-pi-can-boot-nvme-ssds-now
I suspect you haven't set BOOT_ORDER=0xf25416 in the boot loader config correctly, but I can't infer that from your question, really.

I can boot from NVME the native Rpi way , but I'd like to use u-boot

well, u-boot should generally be able to do that. Have you compiled it with support for that?

Lets try this. I suspect it doesn't work, which is why rpi_arm64_defconfig does not enable CONFIG_NVME and CONFIG_NVME_PCI. However, these are the two options to enable to start with to see if "nvme info" then shows information, or not.

I compiled with CONFIG_NVME and CONFIG_NVME_PCI but nothing has changed
